# How do I filter a SQL query by a number of relations?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am having some problems with this homework question:

[image]

I have been able to successfully complete almost all of the query except for the "Only include states with at least 3 diamond mines". I would like to ask how I can add this part to the query.

```
select I.state, sum(P.capacity)
from Infrastructure I
natural join Mine M
join produces P
on P.mine = M.entryno
join Commodity C
on C.comID = P.commodity
where C.name like '%Diamond%'
group by I.state
```

Comment: Hint: use HAVING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your attempt works fine other than condition mentioned in question following query should work:

```
select I.state, sum(P.capacity)
from Infrastructure I
natural join Mine M
join produces P
on P.mine = M.entryno
join Commodity C
on C.comID = P.commodity
where C.name like '%Diamond%'
group by I.state
having count(P.mine) >=3;
```

It will count the no. of commodity for each state as you already has group by on State.

Hope it helps!

Comment: And let's hope there are no mines producing 'pseudo-diamonds'

Comment: I would have used `having count(distinct P.mine) >= 3`

Comment: @Raymond I thought of that too but couldn't figure  the necessity of it without Sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HAVING` clause to count and assert the number of diamond mines:

```
SELECT
    I.state,
    SUM(P.capacity)
FROM Infrastructure I
NATURAL JOIN Mine M
INNER JOIN produces P
    ON P.mine = M.entryno
INNER JOIN Commodity C
    ON C.comID = P.commodity
WHERE
    C.name LIKE '%Diamond%'
GROUP BY
    I.state
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Note: Natural join seems error prone to me and could break at some point.  The best thing to use are explicit joins.